# How to reload the current route after configuration change?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Some times I need to change the layoutTemplate in IronRouter dynamicly, but after I change that using `Router.configure({ layoutTemplate: <a new layout> });`, it does not take effect immediately. It only works after going to other path/route.

Is there a way to reload current Route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses non-public methods, so the API could potentially change, but as things stang it will re-flow the current route:

```
Router.current()._computation.invalidate()
```

Comment: Do you mean `Router.current()._computation.invalidate()` ?